# Find records with unique user_id using distinct/uniq/select and order by

Tags: ruby-on-rails, distinct, uniq

```
<% Activity.where("CAST(code as TEXT) not like ? and CAST(code as TEXT) != ? and CAST(code as TEXT) != ? and user_id IS NOT NULL and user_2_id IS NOT NULL", '%0%', '13', '14').limit(4).order("created_at DESC").each do |activity| %>
```

I keep track of my users' activities with a special table. To show these activities on the front page, I want to select the last four activities (with specific codes) that are from four different people.

I tried different variations of select | distinct | uniq and other solutions, but only receive crashes or errors (e.g. "distinct requires order by in the clause", but no explanation how to do this properly in rails). After trying for three hours, I'm about to give up on this. Help very welcome!

Edit 1: Schema

```
create_table "activities", force: true do |t|
t.integer  "user_id"
t.integer  "recruiter_id"
t.integer  "job_id"
t.integer  "code"
t.integer  "value"
t.integer  "user_2_id"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

The model is simple:

```
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :user_2, class_name: "User"
 belongs_to :recruiter
```

Other info in the model just defines how activities are numbered, but not that relevant here.

I'm interested in getting the last four activities of code between 1-10 from four different users (not the same user again and again).

Edit 2:
The code is just a number. Codes like 1, 2, 3 are actions the user takes, and any code ending in 0 is deleting something (which shouldn't be shown). So 1 is creating an account, 10 is deleting an account.

Comment: Please share the model and schema details. Also, do you want to list latest 4 activities of a particular user(unique id) or just latest 4 activities from anyone? What is `code` in the query?

Comment: Also, what does a typical code look like?  the code not like ? seems like overkill.  Is it just a number?